# RDBMS vs NoSQL in concurrency control for a counter system

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, counter, nosql

I currently have a counter system implemented using Mysql with optimistic locking.  So when there are many concurrent processes accessing the same row in the database to increment the counter in transactions, some of these processes will fail, hence result in overall incorrect count. 
 Using pessimistic locking solves this problem but drastically reduces performance so it's not usable.

When looking at NoSQL options(eg. redis, canandra), I'm wondering if they support these concurrency controls?  If so, are they much more performant than their RDBMS counter-part?

NoSQL is known for storing and updating counters, but how does it deal with concurrency in a way that has more(or less) data integrity than RDBMS?

Comment: You might want to read about the [CAP-Theoreme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). TL;DR version: Fast, Consistent, Distributed: Choose any two.

Comment: What option you selected finally?

Comment: Are you talking about a counter in your program or in a database? In a program, you can use an atomic counter (i.e. sync/atomic package in Golang or AtomicInteger in Java). In general, these low-level libraries use assembly instructions under the hood to ensure only 1 CPU core can access the RAM during the atomic function call. Many databases support counters, but it ultimately boils down to locking or a single thread (no concurrency). Redis, for example, runs a single-threaded event loop.